# How to redirect to respective component in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Could you please tell me How to redirect to respective component in react if `key is not found in local storage` .it will redirect  to `/`.If key is found then it goes respective component

follow the below steps

1  ) add `/pqr` in url .It should redirect to `/abc` or load `Test2` component because local storage have
 key =“a”. Value =`abc`  .

Currently I am able to redirect to home or `/` if there is no value in local storage.using higher oder component

I have a demo app here

https://codesandbox.io/s/00q3588z1v

When I run application with this url “/pqr” full url “https://00q3588z1v.codesandbox.io/pqr”
**expected out it should redirect to `/abc` or load `/Test2` component .**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Redirect, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

    const HocApp = props => {
      console.log("dddddd");
      const user = localStorage.getItem("a") || "";
      console.log(user);

      return <Fragment>{user ? props.children : <Redirect to="/" />}</Fragment>;
    };

    export default withRouter(HocApp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need hocapp you can achieve it by using render function in react router like this:

```
        <Route
          path="/pqr"
          exact
          render={() => {
            const user = localStorage.getItem("a") || "";
            console.log("user", user);
            if (user) {
              return <Redirect to="/abc" />;
            }
            return <Test3 />;
          }}
        />
```